# splashboardd quit unexpectedly caused by TabBarViewController and IBOutlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator

I'm running an App that goes straight to a TabBarViewController.

The problem is that everytime I run the app I get a crash warning letting me know that the splashboardd quit unexpectedly. Then the App runs normally, but I keep getting the same issue everytime I run the App. Here's part of the error:

> "Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key scrollHeight.' terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException abort() called CoreSimulator 117.5.4 -
>   Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 8.2 (12D508) - DeviceType: iPhone 6 "

I've now realized that this only happens when the first tab contains a viewcontroller with outlets of any kind, so when I move a tab (seguing to a view controller that has no outlets)to the first position, or if I remove the outlets in the first VC the error stops...

Has anyone experienced something similar? Since the App runs in the simulator and device, should I worry about this error message?

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, the App runs perfectly normal after getting the message and I'm getting this message in a system window, not Xcode, and I can assure you that the IBOutlets are connected.

**EDIT2:**
"Solved" it, My App didn't had any LaunchScreen File (It was going straight to the storyboard) I added a LaunchScreen File and the error went away... I don't know why this was happening though...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whenever any ios project, if you come to this kind of error "[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]" then open storyboard or xib and look for "!" symbol in connection inspector and remove that.

In you project "scrollHeight" is missing connected outlet.

Comment: I've checked this already and scrollHeight is most certainly connected. The App is actually not crashing (I'm getting this message in a separate window, not Xcode) and If the viewController that contains this Outlet is in the 2nd position of the TabBarController I don't get this message, I only get the message if this VC is in the first position of the TabBarController –  Dkrtemp just now   edit

Comment: "Solved" it, My App didn't had any LaunchScreen File (It was going straight to the storyboard) I added a LaunchScreen File and the error went away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem on IOS 8.3 devices. As soon as the first ViewController contains an IBOutlet, splasboardd crashes. Therefore, I added a LaunchImage Storyboard (as described in the newest [Interface Design Guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)) with a ViewController without any IBOutlets and the splashboardd crashes disappeared.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing, by reading the Guides I just realized that this is "MUST" and not optional. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any ios project, if you come to this kind of error "[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]" then open storyboard or xib and look for "!" symbol in connection inspector and remove that.

In you project "scrollHeight" is missing connected outlet.

Comment: I've checked this already and scrollHeight is most certainly connected. 

The App is actually not crashing (I'm getting this message in a separate window, not Xcode) and If the viewController that contains this Outlet is in the 2nd position of the TabBarController I don't get this message, I only get the message if this VC is in the first position of the TabBarController

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that IBOutlet not connected correct with it's Owner.

When you CMD+Click the File's Owner, then it will indicate, which UIElement is connected twice or not connected.

Find incorrect connection and disconnect will solve the problem